# Rebind JavaScript events and addEventListener fires twice

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a class method which defines the event listeners. Let us use the following code snippet for simplicity.

```js
function bindEvents() {
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log('clicked!');
    }); 
}

// Initial event binding
bindEvents();

// Rebind events at some point for dynamically created elements
bindEvents();
```

```html
<button type="button">Click</button>
```

Everything works fine when using `bindEvents()` only once, however for example calling it again in ajax callback results in listener executed twice. So this means after second `bindEvents()`, clicking the button will `console.log()` twice and so on. Is there a way I can get around this behavior?

I know I can bind the events "dynamically" on the document and check with `e.target`, but there is a situation where I need `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` events and I don't think it's a good idea to always have those `eventListeners` on the document.

I've read somewhere the following, but it seems false...

> The .addEventListener method ensures that the same function reference
> won't be bound more than once to the same element/event/captures
> combination.

Also I have played with the `options` parameter from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener, but without success.

Excuse me if this was answered somewhere, but I failed to find answer in SO and the search engines.

**UPDATE:** Is there a way to overwrite existing eventListeners or old ones should be removed with `removeEventListener` like **kcp** suggested below? Is there more elegant solution to this problem at all?

Answer (score 5):

> The .addEventListener method ensures that the same function reference won't be bound more than once to the same element/event/captures combination.

In your case, each time you execute `bindEvents()` a completely new handler is passed to the `click` event listener since you define new function (no matter it looks the same, it is different object). To use the same handler each time you must define it outside `bindEvents` and pass it by name (by reference). This works as expexted:

```js
function clickHandler(e){
  alert('clicked!');
}

function bindEvents() {
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', clickHandler); 
}

// Initial event binding
bindEvents();

// Rebind events at some point for dynamically created elements
bindEvents();
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```

However with jQuery I use the following approach which allows me to specify that only elements in a specific container (context or ctx) will be bound:

```js
$.fn.bindEvents = function bindEvents(ctx){

 ctx = ctx || this;

 $('button', ctx).on('click', function(event){
  alert(1);
 });
};

$('body').bindEvents();

$('div').bindEvents();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click</button>

<div><button>in div </button></div>
```

In the example above `bindEvents` is executed twice but the first button is bound only once since it's not in a div. While if you click on the second button it alerts twice because satisfies both contexts.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion friend, will do some tests and will come back  with feedback.

Answer (score 2):

`addEventListener` does not overwrite existing event listeners, it simply adds a new one as the method name implies. Existing listeners must be removed using the `removeEventListener` method.

```
function onClick($event) {
    console.log('clicked!');
}
function bindEvents() {
    /** Remove event listener first **/
    document.querySelector('button').removeEventListener('click', onClick);
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', onClick); 
}
```

[`removeEventListener` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It will most certainly work, do you think there is a cleaner solution to the problem perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener), You can also use Event delegation. Using this mechanism event is handler by attaching event listener to parent element.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('div');

elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e = e || event
  var target = e.target;
  if (target.nodeName != 'BUTTON')
    return;

  console.log('clicked ' + target.textContent);
});

//Simulate addition of dynamic elements
setTimeout(function() {
  var newButton = document.createElement('button');
  newButton.innerHTML = 'Click 2';
  elem.appendChild(newButton)
}, 2000)
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It will most certainly work. However as I wrote above there may be mousenter/mouseleave events and I'm not sure if it is a good idea to have those listeners to the document 24/7. What you think about this "problem"?

Comment: @NikolayMihaylov, the advantage we get is that only one event handler is attached

Comment: @NikolayMihaylov and always attach event handler with static parent element