# JavaScript Click event triggers multiple times even if just clicked once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

When I click the `overlay` button, the click even triggers twice, and thus sending the alert message twice.

The click event code is inside the `handler` function.

Also the handler function is called in 'ajax:complete' as:

```
$(handler);
$('ajax:complete', handler);
```

This is done as to reload the handler function, as soon as an Ajax request is made to the page, to reload the Google Map that is embedded in the project.

```
document.getElementById("overlay").addEventListener('click', function () {
            alert("Hello");
        })
```

Comment: Every time you execute handler, you will ADD the eventlistener. So if you execute the handler more than once, you will get an alert for each time handler was executed when you click

Comment: Check if you're calling twice the function that sets the event listener.

Comment: browser really good support for debugging these issues with console.log and debugger. Check if the event attaching multiple times

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rebind JavaScript events and addEventListener fires twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720943/rebind-javascript-events-and-addeventlistener-fires-twice)

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility of duplicate IDs. 
Using duplicate id attribute values is invalid HTML, as HTML specification clearly states that attributes must be unique. Practically, most browsers can handle duplicate ids, but theoretically they can cause issues if the JavaScript is parsing or calling DOM elements based on these id values.
Please check if you are parsing it correctly.